# I have both python3.9 and 3.11 installed and apt is showing unmet dependencies error after I force install pycurl with dpkg

Tags: linux, python, apt

I have both python 3.9 and 3.11 installed, but most of the pip packages is installed in 3.9 and I don't want to move to 3.11

I have to install pycurl, but using pip install it failed to build, so I'm using apt install python3-pycurl, however it's only installing for 3.11

So I manually downloaded it for 3.9
https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/python3-pycurl_7.43.0.6-5_amd64.deb.html

```
# dpkg --force-all -i python3-pycurl_7.43.0.6-5_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 476458 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python3-pycurl_7.43.0.6-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pycurl (7.43.0.6-5) over (7.43.0.6-5) ...
dpkg: python3-pycurl: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 python3-pycurl depends on python3 (<< 3.10); however:
  Version of python3 on system is 3.11.2-1+b1.

Setting up python3-pycurl (7.43.0.6-5) ...
```

After that pycurl works perfectly, but apt is showing error :

```
# apt install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pycurl : Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.11.2-1+b1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It's not a problem as I have both 3.9 and 3.11 installed, it's a false positive

I have to run --fix-broken for apt, otherwise, I can't do anything else with apt, after I run it, it fixed nothing but it broke pycurl for 3.9 and installed it for 3.11

How can I ignore the unmet dependencies error in apt? As it is not a problem at all, and it blocks me from doing anything with pat if I'm not "fixing" it, but in reality its breaking it instead